# UITextField Resigning Sporadically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

This is a really odd issue because I can't give much explanation here. I have UITextField within a UITableView cell. Pretty straightforward...

When I select my UITextField it occasionally just resigns, not allowing the user to interact with the keyboard at all. This happens completely randomly and I don't have the slightest clue why it's happening. Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correct understand, you need push up (resize) your view.

1) Make sure that your textfield's delegate set to viewconntroller.

2) implement methods

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self resizeView:YES toPoint: -70]; // example
   return YES;
}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self resizeView:NO toPoint: 0];
}
```

when resizeView is:

```
-(void) resizeView:(BOOL)top toPoint:(int)point
{
   if (top)
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, point);
}];
   else 
   {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, point);
    }];
   }
}
```

Also you may increase text field frame, may be randomnicity of resigning depend on touch handle by table cell cut not textfield. Try disable user interaction for table or separate cell if this possible to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Would it happen when the cell scrolls offscreen, by any chance?